# populate listview with own layout from database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, android-listview

i am trying to populate a listview with a custom layout with two strings from a database but am experiencing some difficulties. I have tried many methods but none has worked. I hope someone can give me a better solution. Please help me with the custom layout too.

here is the constructor for the database

```
public class Vault {
public Vault() //a constructor is created for the creation of the database
{

}

public static abstract class noteInfo implements BaseColumns // a table is then created
{
    public static final String USER_NAME = "user_name";
    public static final String NOTE = "note";
    public static final String TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "vault";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "note_cabinet";
}

}
```

here is the the adapter for the databse
    public class noteOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int database_version = 1;

```
public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + noteInfo.TABLE_NAME + "(" + noteInfo.NOTE+ " TEXT," + noteInfo.TIMESTAMP + " TEXT," + noteInfo.USER_NAME + " TEXT);";

public noteOperations(Context context) {
    super(context, noteInfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
    Log.d("Note operations", "Database created");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {
    sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    Log.d("Note operations", "Table created");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void putInformation(noteOperations no, String note, String timestamp, String user)
{
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = no.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(noteInfo.NOTE, note);
    cv.put(noteInfo.TIMESTAMP, timestamp);
    cv.put(noteInfo.USER_NAME, user);
    SQ.insert(noteInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    Log.d("Note operations", "One note inserted");
}
public Cursor getInformation(noteOperations no)
{
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = no.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {noteInfo.NOTE, noteInfo.TIMESTAMP};
    Cursor CR = SQ.query(noteInfo.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    Log.d("Note operations", "Table combed");
    return CR;
}
public void deleteUser(noteOperations no, String user_name)
{
    String selection = noteInfo.USER_NAME + " LIKE ? AND " + noteInfo.NOTE + " LIKE ?" + noteInfo.TIMESTAMP + " LIKE ?";
    String args[] = {user_name};
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = no.getWritableDatabase();
    SQ.delete(noteInfo.TABLE_NAME, selection, args);
    Log.d("Databsse operations", "User deleted");
}
public Cursor getallrows(noteOperations no)
{
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = no.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {noteInfo.NOTE, noteInfo.TIMESTAMP};
    Cursor CR = SQ.query(noteInfo.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (CR != null)
    {
        CR.moveToFirst();
    }
    return CR;
}
}
```

here is the xml of the custom layout for the listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bubble_drawable" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/noteView_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timestampView_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/noteView_layout"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: sure, see `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: I still don't get you. can you explain further based on my code ?

Comment: ask uncle google for: `SimpleCursorAdapter`, he will answer with plenty of examples

Comment: oh baby, i see you should **REALLY** improve your googling since the third link from [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=SimpleCursorAdapter&rct=j) is what you need, but it seems that you are **too lazy** for even such simple query

Comment: and a good advice for future, next time try to be more polite and watch your language, got it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html). Ib onCreateViewHolder Create you row view. in onBindViewHolder set data from cursor.
Also read [this](https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/android-list-view-from-database-with-cursor-adapter/).